# Samsung galaxy tab 2 10.1 - read signals from port

Tags: android, signals, port

Is it possible to connect this tab to another device and read signals from port sent from this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some android devices supports communicating throw USB device<--->device via Accessory protocol.

Here is a link that talks in detail about this feature [Android ADK](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html)

To take a more general overview you can start here reading about USB in android: [Android USB Connectivity Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html)

Comment: This link seems to not talks about this feature... But i'll take a look : )

Comment: You can start reading at the link I just added , and then continue to ADK if you still want to.

Comment: Ok, let say that i need to do sth like this using Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1. If i'm right then it doesn't has an usb port. Do u have some advice maybe? BTW. thanks for this link, i'll take a look : )

Comment: It has USB http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/GT-P5113TSYXAR-specs

But you can use bluetooth its easier and more robust